# Как в SQL таблице в одном поле дополнить все записи подстрокой?

Tags: sql, база-данных, mysqli

Переношу сайт с костыльного фреймворка на свой движок, возникла такая проблема:

В таблице БД такие пути к картинкам: `audi/1.jpg`, `bmw/1.jpg` и т.п.
Нужно дополнить пути подстрокой `/uploads/catalog/`, т.е. пути должны быть `/uploads/catalog/audi/1.jpg`

Каталог большой, вручную править не вариант.

Вопрос: как можно одним sql-запросом дополнить все записи в этом поле подстрокой?

Comment: отличные были пути. общую для всех часть лучше хранить где нибудь в настройках приложения. что бы: 1. не править всю БД, если вдруг надо будет изменить путь. 2. Что бы длинные строки не занимали лишнее место на диске. Большие строки снижают производительность

Comment: Не вариант, в админке сайта используется CKFinder, для него по-умолчанию `uploads` является корневым каталогом, и при выборе файла возвращается именно такой путь `uploads/...`, да и много ли я сыкономлю памяти если мне придется везде в шаблонах подставлять подстроку `uploads/catalog/`, в движке множество модулей и для каждого есть своя папка в `/uploads`, к тому же на этом движке я пишу простые информационные сайты, и тратить время и усложнять код ради экономии пары мегабайт - не резон

Comment: а это должно быть ни в коем случае не в шаблонах. а в том коде который достает этот путь из БД например (если конечно есть гарантия, что путь везде одинаков). Идея в том, что любая константа такого рода должна быть где то в системе только в единственном экземпляре, что бы потом было проще исправить, если надо. Но да, при неимении чего то другого, БД лучший вариант по сравнению с шаблонами, исправить явно проще, чем перерывать кучу файлов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update table set field = CONCAT("/uploads/catalog/", field)
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно ;)